# How can I get Chromecast correctly display unicode characters using custom receiver?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, custom-receiver, castcompanionlibrary

I've setup a custom receiver application using CastHelloText-android as a base, and I'm trying to get it to correctly display certain unicode characters, however it is just displaying a blank space instead where the characters should be.

```
<div id="message">Test: &#2613;&#2622;&#2617;&#2623;&#2583;&#2625;&#2608;&#2626; :End Test</div>
```

This renders correctly on the site where I'm hosting the custom receiver, but when attempting to display it using a DataCastManager from the Cast Companion Library, the unicode characters aren't showing up. Is there any way to make this display or is there an alternative?

UPDATE:
I just tried the message:

```
<div id="message">Test: &#2394; &#2613;&#2622;&#2617;&#2623;&#2583;&#2625;&#2608;&#2626; :End Test</div>
```

And the character (ग़) for

```
&#2394;
```

shows up just fine. I'm assuming this is a supported language issue then?

Update2: To help clarify, here is the result I'm getting after casting from a device connecting to my receiver with the above message:
[image: Sample result from unicode character test]

Comment: Using a chrome debugger, what do you get on your receiver when you send this message using  DataCastManager?

Comment: I just found my answer I believe. Adding the character  &#2394; "ग़" will display in Hindi font, but the other characters I was using are from Gurmukhi font and appear as blank. This is probably because Chromecast doesn't support Gurmukhi characters yet?

Comment: You should be able to load that in your receiver.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. It's loading just find in my receiver if viewed from a browser, however the characters show up blank when casting from a device (aside from the Hindi character)

Comment: I mean you should be able to load any fonts that are missing in your own receiver; Chromecast includes a finite set of fonts and if you need something that it doesn't include, then you'd need to load that yourself.

Comment: Good idea, I just tried that as well but unfortunately still no luck. I switched the font to serif, but still no luck rendering the Gurmukhi characters. They show up fine if viewing the receiver HTML page in a browser, but are still blank when viewing from Chromecast. Here is a gist of the receiver code if it helps: https://gist.github.com/kee23/5904213aa29cd9d1463a

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106923/discussion-between-kee23-and-ali-naddaf).

Answer (score 0):

Google responded at: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=794

And thanks Ali, your suggestion was correct. Using a .ttf font and applying it to the text will allow the characters to show up. It's not the same as having the actual unicode characters show up, but still helps.